# Need help resolving Elm error and solving the problem

Tags: elm

I am trying to solve this question:
Define a function subbag that determines whether or not its first argument bag is contained in the second.
subbag : `Bag a -> Bag a -> Bool` (Function Definition)
Note that bag b is contained in bag b′if every element that occurs n times in b occurs also at least n times in b′.

The current code I have:

```
subbag :Bag a -> Bag a -> Bool
subbag j = case j of
    [] -> True
    ((x,n)::xs) -> case  x of
            Just m -> n<=m && subbag xs
            Nothing -> False
```

But I think Elm doesn't have lookup like Haskell and I am also receiving errors with the first case statement
Errors: Something is off with the 1st branch of this `case` expression:

```
39|     [] -> True
              ^^^^
This `True` value is a:

    Bool

But the type annotation on `subbag` says it should be:

    Bag a -> Bool
```

Comment: The most immediate problem, and the cause of the error, is that the type annotation and description specifies two argument, while the implementation only has one.

Comment: Yeah you forgot to put the name of the other bag before the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

This feels a bit like an exercise you've been set, so I'll try to guide and advise you rather than finish the exercise.

You note that elm doesn't have a lookup function like haskell, but a lookup function would be very useful, so why not write one? You could have a look at haskell's lookup function and write very similar code in elm. I'll leave that for you to figure out and assume you've called it lookup

```
lookup : a -> List (a,b) -> Maybe b
lookup a list = Debug.todo "copy some haskell lookup code and make it elm here"
```

Of course what you *really* need isn't just lookup. That's the general tool you reached for because you knew it. General tools are widely useful, and that's probably why you've ended up writing a Bag type. But in this case what you *really* need is `count`:

```
count : a -> Bag a -> Int
count a bag = case lookup a bag of
     Debug.todo "If it's there, return the number, if it's not, return 0"
```

...to make it more specific to your use case, and so that it'll be useful in making your subbag function.

Notice that the `count` function has the type `a -> Bag a -> Int` because it needs a value `a` and a `Bag a` to run, but then importantly, we need to give it both parameters when we define it, so that's why it starts `count a bag`.

You're getting errors because you only gave one name on the left hand side of your function:

```
subbag j = case j of
```

should read

```
subbag j k = case j of
```

The next bit that's a bit garbled is

```
((x,n)::xs) -> case x of
    Just m -> n<=m && subbag xs
    Nothing -> False
```

That means `x` is a `Maybe Int` whereas I think `x` is actually just an `a`.

I would probably not try to do all of `subbag` in one step like you are. Fixing your two mistakes I'd have:

```
subbag : Bag a -> Bag a -> Bool
subbag j k = case j of
    [] -> True
    ((x,n) :: xs) ->  n <= Debug.todo "get how many x there are in j"
                      && subbag xs
```

You've been trying to get how many `x` there are in `j` with a case statement, but I think you need a helper function where you can give it an `x` and a bag and get a number, and now I've come full circle.